# How to add Start Game and Play Again to canvas game?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, game-development

I created game using Javascript following YouTube video game tutorial. Game works just fine, but I would like to add ability to enter nickname at the beginning of the game. After entering nickname and hitting play button the game would begin and nickname would display on the middle upper side of the screen. Then after loosing the game, window with score and play-again button should pop up. After clicking play-again button another game starts.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const collisionCanvas = document.getElementById('collisionCanvas');
const collisionCtx = collisionCanvas.getContext('2d');
collisionCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
collisionCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;

//obsluga gry
let gameOver = false;
let score = 0;
ctx.font = '50px Impact';
let lives = 3;
let hit = false;
let clicked = false;

//setup spawnow
let timeToNextZombie = 0;
let zombieInterval = 400;
let lastTime = 0;
let zombies =[];

//myszka
let innerCursor = document.querySelector('.inner-cursor');
let outerCursor = document.querySelector('.outer-cursor');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveCursor)

function moveCursor(e){
    let x = e.clientX;
    let y = e.clientY;

    innerCursor.style.left = `${x}px`;
    innerCursor.style.top = `${y}px`;
    outerCursor.style.left = `${x}px`;
    outerCursor.style.top = `${y}px`;


}
class Zombie{
    constructor(){
        this.spriteWidth = 200; //szerkosc klatki zombie
        this.spriteHeight = 312; //wyskosc klatki zombie
        this.sizeModifier = Math.random()* 0.8 + 0.6; //mnożnik wielkości zombiaka
        this.width = this.spriteWidth * this.sizeModifier;
        this.height = this.spriteHeight * this.sizeModifier;
        this.x = canvas.width;
        this.y =Math.random() * (canvas.height -this.height); //spawn zombie od dolu do gory ekranu
        this.directionX = Math.random() * 4 + 1; //predkosc zombiakow
        if(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) == 0) this.directionX = 10; //5% szans na szybkiego lopeza
        this.markedForDeletion = false; //oznaczenie czy mozna usunac obiekt
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = 'walkingdead.png';
        this.frame = 0;
        this.maxFrame = 8;
        this.timeSinceFlap = 0;
        this.flapInterval = Math.random()*50+50; //flipowanie kazdego inne
        this.randomColors = [Math.floor(Math.random()*255), Math.floor(Math.random()*255), Math.floor(Math.random()*255)];
        this.color = 'rgb(' + this.randomColors[0] + ',' + this.randomColors[1] + ',' + this.randomColors[2] + ')';
    }


    update(deltatime){
        this.x -= this.directionX;
        this.timeSinceFlap +=deltatime;
        if (this.x < 0-this.width){
            this.markedForDeletion = true;
        }  //zombiak jest poza zasiegiem
        if (this.timeSinceFlap > this.flapInterval){
            if (this.frame > this.maxFrame) this.frame = 0;
            else this.frame++;
            this.timeSinceFlap = 0;
        } 
        if (this.x < 0 -this.width){
            lives-=1;
            if(lives == 0){
                gameOver = true;
            } 
        } 
    } 
    //rysowanie zombiaka
    draw(){
        collisionCtx.fillStyle = this.color;
        collisionCtx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.frame * this.spriteWidth, 0, this.spriteWidth, this.spriteHeight, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}


function drawScore(){
    //kordy scora
    if(lives == 0){
        ctx.font = '200px Impact';
        ctx.fillText('☠️', 0, 170);
        return;
    } 
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillText('Score: ' + score, 55, 80);
    if(lives == 3) ctx.fillText('❤ ❤ ❤', 55, 130);
    if(lives == 2) ctx.fillText('❤ ❤', 55, 130);
    if(lives == 1) ctx.fillText('❤', 55, 130);
}

function drawGameOver(){
    drawScore();
    ctx.font = "bold 100px serif";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillText("GAME OVER!", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2)
    ctx.fillText("Your score is " + score, canvas.width/2, 100 + canvas.height/2)
}

window.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    const detectPixelColor = collisionCtx.getImageData(e.x, e.y, 1, 1);
    const pc = detectPixelColor.data; //popieranie info o hitboxie zombie
    zombies.forEach(object =>{
        if(object.randomColors[0] === pc[0] && object.randomColors[1] === pc[1] && object.randomColors[2] === pc[2]){
            object.markedForDeletion = true; //usunąć gościa z mapy
            hit = true;
        }
        clicked = true;
    })
});
//obsluga klatki
function animate(timestamp) {
    if(clicked){
        if(hit) score+=12
        else score-=6;
        clicked = false;
        hit = false;
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    collisionCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    let deltatime = timestamp - lastTime;
    lastTime = timestamp;
    timeToNextZombie += deltatime;
    if (timeToNextZombie > zombieInterval){
        zombies.push(new Zombie()); //tworzenie nowego zombiaka
        timeToNextZombie = 0;
        zombies.sort(function(a, b){
            return a.width - b.width; //sort zeby mniejsze zombiaki byly za wiekszymi
        })
    };
    drawScore();
    //dla kazdego zombiaka przesuwamy zombiaka, object to pojedynczy (obiekt) zombiaka
    [...zombies].forEach(object => object.update(deltatime)); 
    [...zombies].forEach(object => object.draw());
    zombies = zombies.filter(object => !object.markedForDeletion); //usuwanie zombiakow poza screenem

    if(!gameOver) requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    else{
        drawScore();
        drawGameOver();
    } 
}
animate(0);
```

```css
*{
    cursor: none;
}
canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('board-bg.jpg');
}

#collisionCanvas{
    opacity: 0;
}

.inner-cursor{
    position: fixed;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: white !important;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.outer-cursor{
    position: fixed;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 5px solid white;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Zadanie 12</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
    <canvas id="collisionCanvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>

    <div class="inner-cursor"></div>
    <div class="outer-cursor"></div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your given code snippet does not run

Answer (score 0):

You have everything you need in that code...

```
let gameOver = false;
let zombies = [];
```

all we need is to change a bit your code to take advantage of those.

---

I'm not going to implement your *"window with score and play-again button pop up"* instead I'm going for a much simpler timeout to demonstrate how to restart your game.

---

The key point in your game that sets the "end" is the one below:

```
          if (lives == 0) {
            zombies = []
            gameOver = true;
            gameEnded = Date.now()
            setTimeout(() => { 
              gameOver = false 
              lives = 3
            }, 5000)
          }
```

before you just had the `gameOver` now I'm doing a few more things, like that `setTimeout` that will restart the game in 5 seconds, restarting the game is just to set the gameOver back to false and give the user some lives.

Your `function animate` is where the drawing loop happens, I changed that a bit, now we no longer stop the loop but draw something else and we can add many conditions there:

```
  function animate(timestamp) {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      if (gameOver) {
          drawGameOver();
      } else if (abc < 20) {
          drawABC();
      } else if (def == "start_message") {
          drawDEF();
      } else {
          ...
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }
```

Below is your simplified code with my additions

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.height = 700;

let gameEnded = Date.now()
let gameOver = false;
let score = 0;
ctx.font = '50px Impact';
let lives = 3;
let hit = false;
let clicked = false;

let timeToNextZombie = 0;
let zombieInterval = 400;
let lastTime = 0;
let zombies = [];

class Zombie {
  constructor() {
    this.spriteWidth = 200; //szerkosc klatki zombie
    this.spriteHeight = 312; //wyskosc klatki zombie
    this.sizeModifier = Math.random() * 0.8 + 0.6; //mnożnik wielkości zombiaka
    this.width = this.spriteWidth * this.sizeModifier;
    this.height = this.spriteHeight * this.sizeModifier;
    this.x = canvas.width;
    this.y = Math.random() * (canvas.height - this.height); //spawn zombie od dolu do gory ekranu
    this.directionX = Math.random() * 4 + 1; //predkosc zombiakow
    if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) == 0) this.directionX = 10; //5% szans na szybkiego lopeza
    this.markedForDeletion = false; //oznaczenie czy mozna usunac obiekt
    //this.image = new Image();
    //this.image.src = 'walkingdead.png';
    this.frame = 0;
    this.maxFrame = 8;
    this.timeSinceFlap = 0;
    this.flapInterval = Math.random() * 50 + 50; //flipowanie kazdego inne
  }

  update(deltatime) {
    this.x -= this.directionX;
    this.timeSinceFlap += deltatime;
    if (this.x < 0 - this.width) {
      this.markedForDeletion = true;
    } //zombiak jest poza zasiegiem
    if (this.timeSinceFlap > this.flapInterval) {
      if (this.frame > this.maxFrame) this.frame = 0;
      else this.frame++;
      this.timeSinceFlap = 0;
    }
    if (this.x < 0 - this.width) {
      lives -= 1;
      if (lives == 0) {
        zombies = []
        gameOver = true;
        gameEnded = Date.now()
        setTimeout(() => { 
          gameOver = false 
          lives = 3
        }, 5000)
      }
    }
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke()
  }
}


function drawGameOver() {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.font = "bold 100px serif";
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillText("GAME OVER!", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)
  ctx.fillText("Your score is " + score, canvas.width / 2, 100 + canvas.height / 2)
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.font = "bold 30px serif";
  ctx.fillText("Game will restart in 5 seconds... " + String(Date.now()- gameEnded), canvas.width / 2, 100)
}

function animate(timestamp) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if (gameOver) {
    drawGameOver();
  } else {
    let deltatime = timestamp - lastTime;
    lastTime = timestamp;
    timeToNextZombie += deltatime;
    if (timeToNextZombie > zombieInterval) {
      zombies.push(new Zombie()); //tworzenie nowego zombiaka
      timeToNextZombie = 0;
      zombies.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.width - b.width; //sort zeby mniejsze zombiaki byly za wiekszymi
      })
    };

    [...zombies].forEach(object => object.update(deltatime));
    [...zombies].forEach(object => object.draw());
    zombies = zombies.filter(object => !object.markedForDeletion); 
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
animate(0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```